# SharePoint Online List - export version history

Tags: sharepoint-online, version-history

SharePoint Online/Office 365.

I found a solution [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190021/exporting-item-list-version-history) by adding **&IncludeVersions=TRUE** in the URL but is not very stable, sometimes it will export the history, sometimes it doesnt.

Are there any other way I can export version history of an entire list (not just one item) in SharePoint Online that is more stable?  We can't use PowerShell...

Comment: how do i get the xml after pasting the url ?
nothing happens for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have discovered a fix by accident. I just edited the data connection in Power Query Editor and clicked **Refresh Preview** -- seems to work every time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having the issue you had but I have some difficulties to set it up, could you please help me ?
Sharepoint is giving me an .iqy file without &IncludeVersions=TRUE but when i had it, there is no change when i load this url in my browser.

Do you happen to now what I need to change ?

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer to the main question - here is a short guide [answer] and help others. I see that You have the same problem - please see [ask] new question with extended information about the problem You have and the solution You need (and delete this *answer*).