# Exporting item version check in comments

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, excel, export, versioning

I have followed this [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/190023/32474) to extract the list of versions in my document library to excel:

However, while the table lists all the versions it only displays (and repeats) the most recent check-in a comment.

Is there any other parameter I can add to the .iqy file that will pull out the comment for each version of the document? (or any other method to achieve the same thing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this parameter`$($version['Check In Comment'])` in the PowerShell script to get the `'Check In Comment'`. but unfortunately, it gets only the comment of the **current item** (last version).

So to get the comment for each **previous** version of the document, try this

> `$($item.File.Versions.GetVersionFromLabel($version.VersionLabel).CheckInComment)`

So try to Mix both parameters to get what exactly you need :)

> `$($item.File.Versions.GetVersionFromLabel($version.VersionLabel).CheckInComment),$($version['Check In Comment'])`

---

OR **Download** the full script from [Export the Version Comments and Version Details for each Document in SharePoint](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-the-Version-Comments-4c82dac4) that handle this issue.