# 'Check In Comments' - Export to Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, check-in

### What I want to do

I want to export Document Library data including the Check In Comments.  'Check In Comments' seems to be a special field, perhaps it is not stored in the same 'database' as the Document Library, as when I do an *export to excel* it does not get exported.

I don't want to use Powershell, and besides I'm not skilled in it.  I'm the SP Admin and am just looking for a more straightforward approach.

### The problem

Below is a picture of a list of my documents, you'll note the Check In Comments field (which stored the comments users manually type in to list what's changed in the document e.g. deleted paragraph 2).

[image: picture of a list of documents, displaying Name field, Modified date, Dave's New column yes/no field, Check in Comment standard field and a custom field called CheckInComments_NormalField]

et voilà, as you see in this picture the Check In Comment field is missing, it won't export.
[image: picture of the resultant Excel export, the Check In Comment field is missing...grrrr]

### What I've Tried

I attempted and failed to use JSON to configure the CheckInComments_NormalField (multi-line text field) to display the text that's in the Check In Comment field.

I also tried using a flow to copy the text from the Check In Comments field to my custom multi-line text field, to no avail.  The elusive Check In Comments field can't be included in the Flow, the Flow builder doesn't display it (hence my theory that this is a special field and the info perhaps isn't even stored in the document properties).

### Best Workaround So Far...

My workaround would be to use the Export to Excel and then manually copy and paste the Check In Comments into Excel, which is fine.  It's just annoying that it won't work!

Does anyone have any suggestions?

### Temporary, short-term solutions

Before I go home and consume a quantity of booze to console myself, I thought I'd better post this first.

**Other similar, but not identical questions:**
[Exporting item version check in comments](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/247502/exporting-item-version-check-in-comments)

Comment: We regret that there is no out-of-the-box way to export checked-in comments to an excel in SharePoint Online other than using the export to excel feature. I actually find it convenient to use PowerShell because of its ability to batch process repetitive tasks.

Comment: Can the check-in comments be exported to Excel in Sharepoint 2016 On-Premises?  Or is the behaviour the same?