# Adding version history to exported csv in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I'm essentially trying to do [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190021/exporting-item-list-version-history?newreg=d361bd7e15bb45a9be3c2c8ef559eabd) but when I put the URL in my browser it brings up a generic error. My URL looks like this:

```
https://nfray.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?XMLDATA=1&List={FA6894C6-2BAC-4478-BE6A-218973C7C810}&View=C9789F00-0A9B-4828-A4A6-F010FF8A04D6&RowLimit=0&RootFolder=undefined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, it works well with the url like yours. It will download the xml file when paste the url into the browser. After add "`&IncludeVersions=TRUE`" behind the url, version history will be exported.  Make sure the url is exactly the same as the url in the iqy file.

Besides, try to put the url in other browsers and see if it works.